# VIM in gnome-terminal keeps printing weird 001B character

Tags: gnome-terminal, vim

I have VIM installed on Ubuntu 12.04, and run the terminal version in the gnome-terminal. However, recently (I don't know what caused the change) when editing files in VIM it will sometimes insert a 001B character in a square box when pressing a "wrong" button.

E.g.:
When at the beginning of a line and I press `h` to move left, it will print one of those `OO1B` characters in a box over the leftmost character.

Or, when at the top of a file, and I press `k`, it will print such a character again.

Or when pressing `.` to repeat something without having a command to repeat, it will print such a character.

Each time it prints the character at the current cursor position. I have no idea what causes this.

My terminal profile uses:

- Source Code Pro, Medium - font (but it also happens with system fixed width font)
- Terminal character encoding is set to UTF-8 (But it also happens with other encodings)

It seems like it prints both a `001B` in a square box, and a 'g' at the same cursor position. But it doens't actually 'write' it in the buffer. They are just shown on the screen and remain there until for example I change the character at that cursor position in the buffer. In which case it now shows the correct character again.

[image: Terminal error]

Anybody have any idea what might be causing this? I'm at a loss.

I use the solarized colorscheme, but it runs together with CSApprox because that's the only way I got the colors working almost completely (background for dark background is still off, but everything else is fine).
That's why my `.vimrc` has the following:

```
set t_Co=256  " To make CSApprox not nag
let g:solarized_termcolors=16  "so that solarized uses my terminal presets which I've configured to the solarized colors.
```

I use `syntastic` for highlighting syntax errors.

Comment: Do you have any kind of error highlighting plugin? hex 1B (octal 033) is the escape character, so I'm wondering if it's maybe a broken ANSI color code sequence?

Comment: And what is the TERM variable set to? `echo $TERM` in the shell or in the vim command line?

Comment: $TERM=screen-256color-bce
For error highlighting I use syntastic.

.vimrc has:
set t_Co = 256
let g:solarized_termcolors=16 (because I also use solarized colorscheme)

Comment: Tried without bce? `TERM=screen-256color` - note that setting a `-256color` TERM should be enough, you needn't set `t_Co` as well.

Comment: Should I set this in the `.vimrc` file? Or do I have to put this in a `.bash_profile` for example?

Comment: I've set `set term=screen-256color` in .vimrc, while removing the `set t_Co=256`. That made no changes.
Afterwards I tried putting `export term=screen-256color` in my .bash_profile, resourced, and checked. But alas, that did not change anything either. All of these configurations neither break solarized, but they don't help with the escape characters appearing either.

Comment: @TomP. in `.bash_profile` it would be `TERM` in capitals.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have found the reason those escape appear by disabling everything in my `.vimrc` file and reenabling incrementally. For those people with the same problem, it is caused by the following setting in the `.vimrc` file:

```
set visualbell "Use a visual error indicator instead of a beep
```

Removing the above line fixed the problem.

Silly and logical, but well... There you have it.

Comment: I ran into this in a new computer, running gnome. I like the visual bell (normally it makes the screen flash), but obviously inserting characters that don't go away is annoying. I wonder why this works on some machines and not others.