# Weird character appear when opening file using Vim after installing vim-gnome

Tags: 16.04, gnome, gnome-terminal, vim

I am trying to learn Vim and using .vimrc from [this link](https://github.com/jessfraz/.vim). Everything works fine but after I installed `vim-gnome` via `sudo apt-get install vim-gnome` to use `xterm_clipboard`, weird characters keep printing after I open Vim as in the image below.

[image: img_error_vim]

Everything is still fine if I use `vim -u NONE file`. I checked `$TERM=xterm`.

I found [another question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/598667/vim-in-gnome-terminal-keeps-printing-weird-001b-character) suggesting to delete `set visualbell` in `.vimrc` but it turns out that there is no such line in my `.vimrc`.
I have searched google and found that I can add `set t_TI = t_TE =` to `.vimrc`but it keeps printing the same weird characters but less as in the image below.

[image: img_vim_error]

Could anyone help me how to fix it?

Comment: Welcome to AskUbuntu, are you running Ubuntu via WSL or something like that? It's not how the Gnome Terminal looking like.

Comment: I am using `zsh` shell and custom its theme using [https://github.com/romkatv/powerlevel10k]. The same problem occur when I switched to `bash` as well

Comment: Many things I don't understand what you are doing. If you want to learn Vim, you can execute `vimtutor`. If you want a GUI based vim, `vim-gtk` or `vim-gnome`

Comment: I have already had a basic knowledge of VIM. I was trying to find a way to copy text from VIM to paste to other programs. I searched google and found that it required `xterm-clipboard` which can be done by installed `vim-gnome`. Then I installed it via `sudo apt-get install vim-gnome` and the problem occured

Comment: https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/84/how-can-i-copy-text-to-the-system-clipboard-from-vim

Comment: Now I knew how to copy to clipboard. What I want to ask is how to make those weird characters to disappear. This must be something relating to gnome-terminal but even though when I purge vim-gnome using ` sudo apt-get purge vim-gnome`, the same thing happens

Comment: Try remove .vimrc `rm $HOME/.vimrc` Your action is inconsistent, you installed vim-gnome and not executing it by `vim-gnome` instead you execute `vim` which is a terminal editor. The git could cause the Tofu character (probably wrote by Chinese or Vietnamese or Japanese), I guess.

Comment: I have tried to remove vim-gnome, git repo, purge vim, and reinstall it. But whenever I clone that git repo and apply to .vimrc, the same problem occurs. By the way, it is not Tofu character. It is 001B in a square box followed by >4;2m. I have read somewhere that 001B (hexa) is escape code

Comment: You can complain the git repo editor, not the problem of Ubuntu nor Vim.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just found an answer [here](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/27399/whats-t-te-and-t-ti-added-by-vim-8) for those who might run into the same problem